# Cannot set boolean operator within ArcMap ModelBuilder as True

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, clip, boolean

I'm trying to set up my own tool to automate processing ASCII data (3D laser scanning data exported from the software CloudCompare) and have thus far got everything running pretty much as I would like it to. However, part of my workflow includes clipping an interpolated Raster using a shapefile [Clip (Data Management)].

When processing manually, I select "use input features for clipping geometry", however when I try to set this as an input variable in ModelBuilder, every time I click OK (after selecting the option or setting a boolean variable to True) it immediately reverts to 'False' (I can tell by hovering the mouse over the input).

Any ideas how to force the variable to stay as "True"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could get the Boolean to stay as 'True' was as follows:

1. Add the Boolean as a variable, add the clip tool
2. Add the raster and clip feature
3. Make ANY selection on the clip feature (this is crucial to enable the Boolean in the clip tool)
4. Set the Boolean variable to true
5. Save the model - the Boolean should remain true.
6. You can then clear your selection and run the model.

The reason it keeps reverting back to false when trying to set up the model is that the Boolean for 'Use input features for clipping' is not available unless there is a selection on the clipping feature layer.